# can I use both http auth and sso login in single port using nginx

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I have a single application available through 2 ports. One for users with sso login and other for api users using a httpAuth method. Can I use a conditional method to make both accessible through same port.

## SSO Login - proxy pass

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location ~ ^/(web|search|data)/(.*) {
        access_by_lua_file '/opt/sso/nginx-lua-sso/sso_impl.lua';
    }
}
```

## HTTP Login - proxy pass

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    location ~  ^/(web|search|data)/(.*)  {
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /opt/httpauth/conf/data/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`satisfy any`](http://nginx.org/r/satisfy) directive

```
location ~  ^/(web|search|data)/(.*)  {
    satisfy any;

    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /opt/httpauth/conf/data/.htpasswd;

    access_by_lua_file '/opt/sso/nginx-lua-sso/sso_impl.lua';
}
```